# How to execute node command when some event occur in electron js window

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, electron

I am making a electron js application which have two buttons.
I have assigned click event listners on both of them.
What I want to do uppon someone click them is to increase or decrease brightness respectively.

I have build a function in node.js that does increase the brighthness if we run using sudo command.

Here is the function:

```js
let fs = require("fs");

function inc() {
  var data = fs.readFileSync(
    "/sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl1/brightness",
    "utf-8"
  );

  var newData = parseInt(data) + 10;
  if (newData > 255) {
    newData = 255;
  } else if (newData < 0) {
    newData = 0;
  }
  newData = newData.toString();

  fs.writeFileSync(
    "/sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl1/brightness",
    newData,
    "utf-8"
  );
}
```

The index.html code is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Clock App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="incBright()">+</button>
    <button onclick="decBright()">-</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to execute the inc() function when someone click on the'+' button!
[elctron js app window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpUAT.png)

Can someone tell me is that even possible to do that or not.

I am using linux

I don't have any idea about this stuff

Comment: You can use the electron build in ipc chanel to communicate to the "backend" or set the node integration to true.

Comment: Where is `incBright()` and `decBright()` defined in your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To communicate between the main thread and render thread(s) you will want to become familiar with Electron's [Inter-Process Communication](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/) and [Context Isolation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation).

Additionally, you will want to become familiar with Electron's [ipcRenderer](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer) and [ipcMain](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-main) modules.

---

On brightness adjustments, you will want to communicate that adjustment to the main thread through the use of IPC. To safely communicate to the main thread, one should use a `preload.js` script.

The `preload.js` script is integrated into the construction of your application window, allowing permissible actions to take place.

Below is a preload script that uses "channel names" to convey information to and from the main thread and render thread(s).

> Is a good design decision not to implement concrete functions directly within your `preload.js` script. Instead, use you preload script as a gate keeper to only allow messages between threads. This will greatly simplify your preload script and separate your concerns.

Below is an example of a preload script that will fulfill your requirements, noting the use of the channel names `brightness:increment` and `brightness:decrement`. You can rename these channel names to whatever you like.

`preload.js` (main thread)

```js
// Import the necessary Electron components.
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// White-listed channels.
const ipc = {
    'render': {
        // From render to main.
        'send': [
            'brightness:increment',
            'brightness:decrement'
        ],
        // From main to render.
        'receive': [],
        // From render to main and back again.
        'sendReceive': []
    }
};

// Exposed protected methods in the render process.
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    // Allowed 'ipcRenderer' methods.
    'ipcRender', {
        // From render to main.
        send: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.send;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.send(channel, args);
            }
        },
        // From main to render.
        receive: (channel, listener) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.receive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                // Deliberately strip event as it includes `sender`.
                ipcRenderer.on(channel, (event, ...args) => listener(...args));
            }
        },
        // From render to main and back again.
        invoke: (channel, args) => {
            let validChannels = ipc.render.sendReceive;
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                return ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, args);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

---

Now that our preload script is configured, let's utilise it in the construction of our application window.

Additionally, let's listen on these message channels, and when detected, call our `adjustBrightness` function.

`main.js` (main thread)

```js
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
const electronIpcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

const nodeFs = require("fs");
const nodePath = require("path");

// Prevent garbage collection
let window;

function createWindow() {
    const window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false, // For safety, let's disable Node integration
            contextIsolation: true, // For safety, let's enable context isolation
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js') // Let's use our preload script
        }
    });

    window.loadFile('index.html')
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    return window;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});

// Let's listen for messages to increment or decrement the brightness
electronIpcMain.on('brightness:increment', () => {
    adjustBrightness(10);
})

electronIpcMain.on('brightness:decrement', () => {
    adjustBrightness(-10);
})

// Function to adjust screen brightness
function adjustBrightness(adjustment) {
    let data = nodeFs.readFileSync('/sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl1/brightness', 'utf-8');

    let newData = parseInt(data) + adjustment;

    if (newData > 255) {
        newData = 255;
    } else if (newData < 0) {
        newData = 0;
    }

    newData = newData.toString();

    nodeFs.writeFileSync('/sys/class/backlight/amdgpu_bl1/brightness', newData, 'utf-8');
}
```

---

Lastly, let's make sure our rendered html sends the messages out to the main thread when the corresponding buttons are clicked.

`index.html` (render thread)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Clock App</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="button" id="incBrightness" value="+">
        <input type="button" id="decBrightness" value="-">
    </body>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('incBrightness').addEventListener('click', () => {
            window.ipcRender.send('brightness:increment');
        })

        document.getElementById('decBrightness').addEventListener('click', () => {
            window.ipcRender.send('brightness:decrement');
        })
    </script>
</html>
```